# c# code to check string values in line from text file

Tags: c#

like : Gpu 0x00000100 g0 c670 4h 8w h0 ON h1 -- h2 -- h3 --

I want to check string after h0,h1,h2 and h3 is ON or not

here is my code :

```cs
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string find = "h0";

    if (line.Contains(find))
    {
        //int i = line.IndexOf(find);
        //string authorName = line.Substring(i, i + );
        Console.WriteLine(line);

        string[] authorInfo = line.Split(' ');
        foreach (string info in authorInfo)
        { 
            int i = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", info.Substring(info.IndexOf(": ") + 1));
            if(info.Substring(info.IndexOf(": ")+1)=="h0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0}", info.Substring(info.IndexOf(": ") + 2));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression to find h[0-9] followed by the state (ON or --):  `(h[0-9]+) ((ON|--))`. This can be done with System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex:

```cs
string line = "Gpu 0x00000100 g0 c670 4h 8w h0 ON h1 -- h2 -- h3 --";
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(line, @" (?<variable>h[0-9]+) (?<state>(ON|--))");
foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{m.Groups["variable"].Value} is {m.Groups["state"].Value}");
}
```

Output:

```
h0 is ON
h1 is --
h2 is --
h3 is --
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a modern c#, you can use String split that takes an array of strings to split on

```
string x = "Gpu 0x00000100 g0 c670 4h 8w h0 ON h1 -- h2 -- h3 --";
var seps = new[]{" h0 "," h1 "," h2 "," h3 "};

var bits = x.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Also with your modern c# you can use the "indices and ranges" feature to easily get the last elements of the array:

```
var h0 = bits[^4];
var h1 = bits[^3];
var h2 = bits[^2];
var h3 = bits[^1];
```

Think of the `^` character as being replaced by `bits.Length-`, therefore in an array of length 10, `bits[^1]` is like `bits[bits.Length-1]` ie index 9, the last in the array

If your c# is older and doesn't support this syntax you can still use `bits[bits.Length-1]` etc

You could also get the results as another array rather than separate variables, again using ranges

```
var hs = bits[^4..];
```

`hs` is an array, with the `h0` value in `hs[0]` and so on

---

You could use a bit of LINQ for a one liner:

```
x.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.None).Reverse().Take(4).Reverse().ToArray()
```

but it wouldn't be as efficient